# How to prevent Spring from using a @Configuration that's in a test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I've got this in a spring configuration xml file that I want to load explicitly and it has this inside:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="my.path" />
```

I'm loading it like this in a test:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"/beans.xml"})
```

The problem is, apparently this scan is able to see an `@Configuration` that's nested inside another test because this test is in a package that's under the  `base-package`.  For the purpose of my test, this is undesired behavior.  Is there a way I can prevent this from occurring?  I don't this `component-scan` to load `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: A slightly more pressing question is, why are you allowing test classes and their configurations to pollute the actual classpath?

Comment: @Makoto I'm not sure of an alternative way.  Don't tests go on the classpath by running them?  How else could you run them?  This blog article I wrote explains in detail what I'm trying to achieve (I ask this question because I noticed an issue with it): http://www.sleepeasysoftware.com/how-to-mock-out-a-deeply-nested-class-in-spring-without-going-insane/

Comment: Oh.  That's straightforward enough to port into IntelliJ and figure some things out...

Comment: @Makoto thanks, that was my intent :)

Comment: @Makoto also, if you can come up with a better solution that Biju, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: So, at least from the example in the blog post, you're using a mock database system.  Are you using a mock database as well?  If you are, there's not much reason to involve Spring at all - you'd just be faking the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.path" >
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" 
        expression="org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration" />        
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: That's awesome and works.  Is there any way to filter this way: Exclude `@Configuration`s that are nested in test classes?

Answer (score 2):

The *general* approach to avoid this in tests with Spring is to have the test load its own context configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4Runner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/path/to/beans.xml"})
public class SpringDatabaseTest {

}
```

Note that, with IntelliJ's component scan (which is pretty accurate), the troublesome configuration no longer appears:

[image]

Now comes the problem of the goal of the test.  What are you **intending** to test?  Do you want to pretend that the wiring works and that you'll get data back?  Do you want to verify actual interactions with the wired beans?

If you want to do the former, **do not use Spring for this.**  Instead, use Mockito in its entirety.  There's no sense in injecting a handful of beans here and there but mocking out the rest; it leads to confusing and inconsistent tests.

You would have to add some setter properties to the classes you needed to inject mocks into, and also initialize them yourself, but that can be handled in an `init` function anyway.

From the blog you linked to, this is the full code of the mocked-out database test.

```
package mavensnapshot;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Answers;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockDatabaseTest {

    @Mock
    private Database mockRepo;

    @InjectMocks
    private Middle middle;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        End end = new End();
        end.setDatabase(mockRepo);
        middle.setEnd(end);
    }

    @Test
    public void testReplaceRepositoryWithMock() {
        doNothing().when(mockRepo).save();
        middle.useEnd();
        verify(mockRepo).save();
    }
}
```

If you want to do the latter, **absolutely use Spring.**  There's no other way around it, to be blunt.  At this point, you now have to verify the complete interaction with the code, not just a sliver like you can do with mocks.  This also depends on how you set it up; I would rather prefer that each class gets its own test instead, assuming that the layers below it work fine, then forcing a concrete test at the lowest layer, and introducing a more complete integration test at the highest layer.

Same project, different style of test:

```
package mavensnapshot;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/beans.xml"})
public class SpringDatabaseTest {

    @Autowired
    private Middle middle;

    @Test
    public void testMiddle() {
        middle.useEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the indepth reply and I am very aware that that's usually the way people write unit tests.  To be extremely pedantic, this doesn't really answer my question, but says, "do something else instead".  Although the majority of devs who write spring tested code would agree with you, there are other philosophies out there.  Personally, I follow this one: http://vimeo.com/68375232

Comment: That video is also very long and most won't have time to watch (but I highly recommend).  This is a much shorter read: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html  Notice the part about *Collaborator Isolation*: "But not all unit testers use this isolation. Indeed when xunit testing began in the 90's we made no attempt to isolate unless communicating with the collaborators was awkward (such as a remote credit card verification system)."